# How can I upgrade pip when there is a folder missing in the path it's trying to access?

Tags: pip

I keep receiving the following message:

You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

However, when I try, I am met with this error:

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/.umpy-1.15.4.dist-info/METADATA'

I had several errors exactly like this, and I noticed that METADATA was in the right place, but that there was an additional folder that was not included in the path above. I was able to get around this by moving METADATA out from the extra folder and into the folder listed in the error message above.

However, when I try to do that with this path, I notice the .umpy-1.15.4.dist-info directory does not even exist.

I struggling to understand if there's an easier way to accomplish this, or if I have messed up with my installation to being with.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, before doing anything, always have a backup copy of pip which is generally in `pythonxxx/Lib/site-packages`

you can try below command
`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

it will install updated pip and keep existing pip packages